# Encoding Actions with Parameters in Neural Network Output

Tags: neural-networks, game-ai

I have a task which I would like to teach an AI to perform. The input to the task will a screenshot of the screen and the output at any given time step is one of the following actions:

```
    DoNothing
    Click(x, y)
    Drag(from_x, from_y, to_x, to_y)
    KeyPress(Key)
    LongKeyPress(Key, duration)

where:
    Key ∈ { 1 , 2 , 3 , 4 , Space , Up , Down , Left , Right }
```

I think that deciding which action to take could be done with a softmax output layer, but I don't know how I would also encode the parameters of each action. For example, the `Click` action also 2 co-ordinate values but the `Drag` action needs 4 co-ordinates.

My best idea at the moment is that I could use one neural network to decide on which action type to perform and for each action, train another network to decide the parameters. So for example I have the main network which decides to take a `Click` action, and then a secondary network which will choose the `x` and `y` co-ordinates (given the same input).

The problem with this is that I would end up training 6 networks (decide the action, `Click` co-ordinates, `Drag` co-ordinates, `KeyPress` key, `LongKeyPress` key, `LongKeyPress` duration). The drawback for this is that I would need a very large dataset with a lot of samples for each type.

I considered how it might be possible to encode all the values into one output, but I wouldn't know how to deal with missing values (for samples where the user clicked, what value should i use for the `Key` output of `KeyPress`).

I have tried to find research papers on the topic, but I must be missing the right keywords because I can't find anything about strategies for this problem. Any ideas or pointers to relevant material would be great!

Comment: I think your problem would fit to reinforcement learning, but you also mentioned a dataset - so the main question is: Given a screenshot, is there one and only one correct action to perform? If yes, I think you are on the right track with classification, If No you should explore the realm of [reinforcement learning (RL)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reinforcement_learning).
Also, if this is RL, the number of possible actions is enormous (especially the continuous actions click + drag & drop) which makes the task really hard and you might want to simplify the actions a bit.

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot explore the possibility of RL because I do not have a test environment in which the agent can 'practice'. Besides this, I will mention that I am not interested in finding the *most efficient* solution, but instead the *most human-like* solution. That is why I would like the agent to learn from a dataset of actions made by a human. I know that I might also be able to use a GAN architecture for this but that is something I have no done before. Also I am aware that the action space is huge, but I cannot see a feasible way to reduce it without also reducing expressiveness.